# Histogram program aid

Tags: c++

I am a bit stuck with my program, The program is to Read in a set of results and then construct a histogram  that indicates how many marks are in each decade i.e how many between 10-20 etc.

I have 2 problems

1. How can I edit my code to only allow the readExamResults to store ones in the range of 0 -100
2. How can I get the PrintHisto to print the * at a certain setw() dependant on which decade each of the results where in. e.g. If I entered 3,4,5,11,23 It should show 3 * in the <10 decade, 1 in the 10-20 decade and 1 in the 20-30 decade.

any help will be much appreciated.

code:

```
using namespace std;

 void readExamMarks(int examMarks[], int sizeOfArray){

cout << "Please enter a set of exam marks to see a histogram for:" << endl;
int x = 0;
for( int idx = 0; idx < sizeOfArray; idx++){

    cin >> x;
    examMarks[idx] = x;
}
}

void printExamMarks(int examMarks[], int sizeOfArray){

for(int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){

    cout << setw(5) << examMarks[x];
}
cout << endl;
}

 void printHisto(int examMarks[], int sizeOfArray){
system("cls");

for( int x = 0; x < 6; x++){
cout << setw(5) << "*" << endl;
}
}

int main() 
{
int examMarks[5];

readExamMarks(examMarks, 5);
printHisto(examMarks, 5);
printExamMarks(examMarks,5);


system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: For the second part consider looking at [`Counting sort`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I edit my code to only allow the `readExamResults` to store ones
>   in the range of 0 -100

I guess you meant `readExamMarks` rather than `readExamResults`. If so, you would just need to add an `if` statement to check that the input value is actuall in the range [0..100]. I have also changed your loop statement `for` to a `while` because you just want to increase `idx` when a valid number is entered.

```
void readExamMarks(int examMarks[], int sizeOfArray)
{
     cout << "Please enter a set of exam marks to see a histogram for:" << endl;
     int x = 0;
     int idx = 0;
     while(idx < sizeOfarray)
          cin >> x;
          if((x >=0) && (x <= 100)){
               examMarks[idx] = x;
               idx++;
          }
          else
               cout << "ERROR: Value must be in range [0...100], please enter a valid value\n"; 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you create a new array with an entry for each decade. Then iterate over the exam grades and increase the according decade in the histogram:

```
vector<int> calculateHistogram(vector<int> grades) 
{
    vector<int> histogram(10, 0);
    for (int i=0; i<grades.size(); i++) {
        int decade = grades[i]/10;
        histogram[decade] += 1;
    }
    return histogram;
}
```